# How to do custom validation in ngTagsInput(not regex)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, angularjs-directive, ng-tags-input

For example I want to add custom validation where addedValue<20, how to implemenet it?

```
<tags-input ng-model="numbers"
        placeholder="Add a number"
        min-length="1"
        max-length="3"
        allowed-tags-pattern="^[0-9]+$"
        onTagAdded="$tag<20"></tags-input>
```

this is code I use.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use the `on-tag-adding` attribute to check if it's a valid tag:

```
<tags-input ng-model="numbers" 
            placeholder="Add a number" 
            min-length="1"
            max-length="3"
            on-tag-adding="checkTag($tag)">
</tags-input>
```

In your controller:

```
$scope.checkTag = function(tag) {
    // check if its a valid number and smaller than 20
    return !isNaN(tag.text) && +tag.text < 20;
}
```

Comment: Does on-tag-adding work with promises. Cause I was checking if we could  fire a http request with the tag as payload, and validate based on the response. ?